# How to get started (Build) Presto on Windows

Tags: presto

I see clear requirements that for building presto you need Mac OS/Linux.
https://github.com/prestodb/presto
I also see there are issues which are being discussed on getting windows support for Presto's build
https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/2351

What I don't see is a proper documentation of how to get started or a way around to get started with windows.

I found this link http://wheresthedocs.blogspot.com/
but I am not sure is it going to help me in getting started with presto.
If anyone has done it please provide with some basic instructions that would be very helpful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presto does not currently support building or running on Windows.  There is a community member slowly working on getting this to work, but it is not something Facebook is working on.

In the mean time, I suggest you use Vagrant or VirtualBox to run virtualized Linux on your Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

Someone at Microsoft got this working on Azure last year with a few tweaks. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mostlytrue/archive/2014/08/12/more-blue-coffee-presto-on-azure.aspx